# list.files returns always directories

Tags: r

Why `list.files()` returns directories and files?

Indeed the help states:

> include.dirs
>   logical. Should subdirectory names be included in recursive listings? (They always are in non-recursive ones)."

Code and output (Windows 10):

```
list.files(R.home(), include.dirs =FALSE)
 [1] "bin"            "CHANGES"        "COPYING"        "doc"           
 [5] "etc"            "include"        "library"        "MD5"           
 [9] "modules"        "README"         "README.R-3.6.3" "share"         
[13] "src"            "Tcl"            "tests"          "unins000.dat"  
[17] "unins000.exe"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
length(list.files(R.home(), include.dirs = TRUE, recursive=TRUE))
length(list.files(R.home(), include.dirs = FALSE, recursive=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed the part "(They always are in non-recursive ones)." in the documentation.